# Can you use Tavern Brawler to wield a 2 handed sword with one hand as an improvised weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons, improvised-weaponry

So I'm wielding a two handed sword. Can I grapple with one hand and use the 2hd sword as a improvised weapon? Obviously the damage dice would be less.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Penalty for trying to use a two-handed weapon with one hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115693/penalty-for-trying-to-use-a-two-handed-weapon-with-one-hand)

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Are Improvised Weapons used in melee actually melee weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119926)"

Comment: @NeutralVax That question is looking for answers that don't have to do with improvised weapons, so I feel like these are different questions (and with different answers)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5):

## You do not need Tavern Brawler

[Improvised Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#ImprovisedWeapons) will let you wield a 2h sword in 1 hand:

> An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a dead goblin.

It goes without saying that a sword is an object.

Comment: @Medix2 I add explicit information about Tavern Brawler, I'm not sure if I want to assume that the player has no idea how improvised weapons work, I generally prefer more focused answers rather than info dumping everything possibly related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, but Tavern Brawler isn't required.

PHB, p. 147

> An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands.

Assuming you can hold the sword in one hand, you can use it as an improvised weapon.

PHB, p. 148

> An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage.

As the sword resembles a weapon, the DM would select the damage die.

Even though it's not required, Tavern Brawler still has some benefits.
As per Tavern Brawler, you would have proficiency on the attack roll.

> You are proficient with improvised weapons

Tavern Brawler also allows you attempt a grapple on a bonus action after making an attack with an improvised weapon.

> When you hit a creature with an unarmed strike or an improvised weapon on your turn, you can use a bonus action to attempt to grapple the target.

Comment: Isn't there a difference between "wield in one hand" and "hold in one hand"?

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Here's a video of someone using a two handed sword with one hand. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbNL_At0IVw

Comment: Why would the DM determine the damage die?

Comment: @NautArch It says if the weapon bears no resemblance to a weapon you default to a d4

Comment: @NautArch I initially misread the "DM selects the damage type" section. I still stand by interpretation though.

Comment: I'd be very wary as a DM to turn a two-handed/heavy weapon into a versatile one. That's pretty powerful.

Comment: @NautArch I'd just probably give it a d4 or at most a d6

Comment: @NautArch I'd don't think it's making it a into a versatile weapon, more like making it into a club

Comment: @NautArch What should I do to improve my answer.